# Lock User and Enforce Password change via wp-cli

Tags: wp-cli

Via wp-cli I want on automated installation scripts to either:

- "lock" and send an email to enforce to follow a "forgotten password" link via a custom email.
- Enforce a user on first login to change his/her password.

So I can apply an user policy via automation scripts for my custom docker solution such as [this](https://github.com/ellakcy/wordpress-with-plugins) one.

So do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Would [`wp user reset-password {username}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/reset-password/) work for your purposes? The docs are a little thin, but I gather it sets the password for `{username}` to a random string, then emails that string to the email address on record for `{username}`.